# como percorrer todos os elementos de um vetor php com javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

como posso percorrer todos os elementos de um vetor php em javascript pois o meu javascript somente pega o ultimo nome mas meu 'var_dump()' esta recendo todos como posso fazer isso alguem pode me ajudar?

codigo php:

```
 foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd){
                              $sql   = "SELECT *  FROM produtos WHERE id_produto= '$id'";
                              $qr    = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                              $ln    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);

                              $nomes  = $ln['nome'];
                              $preco = $ln['preco'];
                              $sub   = $ln['preco'] * $qtd;
                              $img   = $ln['img'];
                              $desc  = $ln['descricao'];
                              $id    = $ln['id_produto']; 


                              $nomes = array($nomes);
                              $nomes = implode("|", $nomes);
                              var_dump($nomes);

                    }
```

codigo javascript:

```
var i, array_produtos, string_array;
        //recebe a string com elementos separados, vindos do PHP
        string_array = "<?php echo $nomes; ?>";
        //transforma esta string em um array próprio do Javascript
        array_produtos = string_array.split("|");

        //varre o array só pra mostrar que tá tudo ok
        for (i in array_produtos)
        alert(array_produtos[i]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instância uma variavel fora do foreach, ele está reescrevendo.

> PHP

```
$final_result = "";
 foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd){
                          $sql   = "SELECT *  FROM produtos WHERE id_produto= '$id'";
                          $qr    = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                          $ln    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);

                          $nomes  = $ln['nome'];
                          $preco = $ln['preco'];
                          $sub   = $ln['preco'] * $qtd;
                          $img   = $ln['img'];
                          $desc  = $ln['descricao'];
                          $id    = $ln['id_produto']; 

                          $final_result .= "|" . $nomes;

                }
```

> Java Script:

```
var i, array_produtos, string_array;
        //recebe a string com elementos separados, vindos do PHP
        string_array = "<?php echo $final_result; ?>";
        //transforma esta string em um array próprio do Javascript
        array_produtos = string_array.split("|");

        //varre o array só pra mostrar que tá tudo ok
        for (i in array_produtos)
        alert(array_produtos[i]);
```

**Segue abaixo uma maneira mais inteligente de se obter os dados.**

> PHP (Pegue todos os dados e tranforme em json)

```
$final_result = array();
foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd){
        $sql   = "SELECT *  FROM produtos WHERE id_produto= '$id'";
        $qr    = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $ln    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);

        //Não sei se já existe quantidade em banco mas caso não exista estou setando ela manualmente abaixo:
        $ln['quantidade'] = $qtd;

        //Detalhe todos os campos do banco já estão no vetor inclusive nome img descricao etc...

        array_push($final_result, $ln);
}

$fjson = json_encode($final_result);
```

> Javascript

```
var i, produtos;
//recebe o objeto json do php
produtos = <?php echo $fjson; ?>;

//varre o array só pra mostrar que tá tudo ok
for (i in produtos)
{
    alert("Nome: " + produtos[i].nome + "\nQuantidade: "+produtos[i].quantidade);
}
```

Comment: intendi muito obrigado

Comment: desse jeito que voce explicou nao tem como fazer tipo pra ele pegar a quantidade do produto tipo o produto 1 tem 2 quantidade e o produto 2 tem 3 quantidades. ai desse modo ele ira imprimir assim: produto1 | produto 2 2 | 3 nao teria como eu imprimir respectivamente? ex: produto1 quantidade 2 | produto 2 quantidade 3 ?

Comment: Então o correto seria você fazer o uso do json, e converter ele para um objeto javascript

Comment: vou editar a resposta.

Comment: Pronto a resposta esta adaptada

Comment: no alert a quantidade entra como undefined tipo nao tem problema pq isso eu vou mandar pro email por ajax?

Comment: a quantidade não tava no vetor... eu já arrumei novamente a resposta

Comment: ou dá um +1 ai na reposta agora ela ficou mais completa

Comment: e obvio q vou dar +1

Comment: funcionou a quantidade?

Comment: funcionou agr estou tentando mandar os dados via ajax

Comment: cara voce sabe como que eu quando clicar pra finalizar a compra ele me enviar um email e ao mesmo tempo chamar o form do pagseguro passando o valor total da compra nao consigo fazer por causa do action do pagseguro vc tem alguma ideia? tipo assim eu so vou mandar o valor total para o pagseguro e esse exemplo que vc respondeu para pegar todos os dados eu vou passar por email

Comment: Então @LeonardoCosta essa já seria uma outra pergunta, mas procure sobre o PHP Mailer e o uso do AJAX.

Comment: tipo cara eu sei fazer isso ja uso a muito tempo o php mailer e o ajax tbm tenho varias coisas usando os 2 mas d boa cara vlw pela resp ai

Comment: precisar só perguntar ;)

Comment: Já que se usou Javascript, seria bom manter as linguagens separadas uma das outras, com base no modo como operam.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um exemplo de como você poderia fazer isso usando a função json_encode do php:

```
<?php

$nomes = array(
  'nome1',
  'nome2',
  'nome3',
  'nome4',
  'nome5',
);

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var nomes = <?php echo json_encode($nomes); ?>;

for (var nome in nomes) {
  console.log(nomes[nome]);
}

</script>
```

**json_encode**: Essa função retornar uma representação em formato json da variável que é passada como argumenta para ela. No exemplo acima ela ira retorna a string abaixo, que em javascript é interpretado como um array:

```
["nome1","nome2","nome3","nome4","nome5"]
```

Aplicando essa função no seu código, ele poderia ficar da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

$result = array();    

foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd){
  $sql   = "SELECT *  FROM produtos WHERE id_produto= '$id'";
  $qr    = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  $ln    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);

  $nomes  = $ln['nome'];
  $preco = $ln['preco'];
  $sub   = $ln['preco'] * $qtd;
  $img   = $ln['img'];
  $desc  = $ln['descricao'];
  $id    = $ln['id_produto']; 

  $result[] = $nomes;

}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">

var i, array_produtos;
//recebe a string com elementos separados, vindos do PHP
array_produtos = <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>;
//transforma esta string em um array próprio do Javascript

//varre o array só pra mostrar que tá tudo ok
for (i in array_produtos)
    alert(array_produtos[i]);

</script>
```

Comment: nao da certo fazer desse jeito ele continua retornando o ultimo numero

Comment: Eu editei o script agora deve funcionar.